# Expectations when contacted by an acquisitions editor about a course I teach

Tags: publications, books

This morning I received the email I've posted below, which says it comes from an "acquisitions editor."
1. What should I expect from a meeting if I agree to meet with the rep?
2. Is Kendall/Hunt a trustworthy company?

"Dear Professor Cruiser,

My name is [redacted] and I am an Acquisitions Editor with Kendall/Hunt Publishing Company.

As an Editor, I am particularly interested in speaking with you about the business math course that you teach.  I am curious to learn how the particular course is taught and the materials being used.

I am not a textbook rep. I am going to be at the [redacted] University campus during the week of [redacted] and I would like to meet with you during my visit.

Please let me know what day(s) and time(s) works best for us to speak during the week of [redacted].

I look forward to meeting you!

Kindest regards,

[redacted]

Acquisitions Representative"

Comment: That company has somewhat of a reputation as a vanity press, see e.g. [this](https://www.chronicle.com/forums/index.php?topic=60440.0), but if the person contacting you isn't a textbook rep it need not be a res flag. (That is, there are certainly legitimate reasons for small press runs in some cases.)

Answer (score 8):

I would probably ignore such a message, but if you want to know what to expect from a hypothetical meeting, I suggest asking the person who emailed you, since they weren't very specific. Why do they want to know about your course? What's in it for them, and what's potentially in it for you? If they can't or won't give you clear answers to those questions before the meeting, you can conclude they are not worth your time.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at their website, it looks like a self publishing shop.  Which is even worse than a textbook hack.

I would blow it off.  You have better use for your time. And better people to endorse, even by a meeting.